# How to sell a new idea – “100% secure communication”, feedback wanted

Tags: encryption, email, sms

I have thought of an idea (new product) to have 100% secure communication between 2 parties and would like your feedback/ideas on how to sell it.
Oh, before you start that there is no such thing as 100% secure encryption, please bare with me, and just see it as a philosophical concept.
Lets imagine that somebody has really thought of a way and wants to make a bug out of it, how would you do it?

I don’t have the right connections but have a few ideas…
Sure a lot of other people claim the same so just saying you have an idea doesn’t mean much so I guess we need proof of concept.
I could encypt a message with my method, make that public and offer a reward for the first to decrypt it.

As with all products, there are a few limitations but 
Regarding making some money of tthis idea…I could write an App and offer it as a service but I prefer to sell it to either 1 big party or a few.

I’m very interested on what you would do, if you had thought of a way to create 100% secure encryption.
Thanks,

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Also, is your solution TLS? If it's not, why not use TLS? If you don't understand the benefits - and the problems - of TLS (or any of the other existing cryptoprotocols), then you are guaranteed that you are either doing it wrong, or doing it oh so very, very wrong.

Comment: Also, challenges of the form "decrypt this encrypted message" are a sure sign that you are not understanding the basics of how cryptanalysis, and cryptography in general, work. Start by looking up [Kerkchoffs Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle).

Answer (score 2):

Try to assign a patent for your new encryption method. And try to sell licences or your patent. That's what the [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29#Patent) guys have done.

But keep the [Kerckhoffs's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle) in mind, and publish your algorithm. Because history has shown most proprietary algorithms fail, due to design errors.